# how do I stop NaN being displayed in the results?

Tags: jquery, nan

I've got this jquery script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(function(){
    $("#result").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var ele = $("#element").val(),
        target = $("#target").val(),
        context = $("#context").val(),
        border = $("#border").val(),
        margin = $("#margin").val(),
        padding = $("#padding").val();

    console.log(ele, target, context, border, margin, padding);

    var DoubleMargin = parseInt(margin, 10) * 2;
    var DoublePadding = parseInt(padding, 10) * 2;
    var DoubleBorder = parseInt(border, 10) * 2;


    var ActualTarget = parseInt(target, 10) - parseInt(DoubleBorder, 10) - parseInt(DoubleMargin, 10) - parseInt(DoublePadding, 10) * 1;
    var result3 = parseInt(target, 10) - parseInt(DoubleMargin, 10) * 1;
    var MarginResult = parseInt(margin, 10) / parseInt(target, 10) * 100;
    var PaddingResult = parseInt(padding, 10) / parseInt(target, 10) * 100;
    var OriginalResult = parseInt(ActualTarget, 10) / parseInt(context, 10) * 100;
    var BorderResult = parseInt(target, 10) - parseInt(border, 10) * 1;

    //$(".result").append(ele + " " + result + "%");
    $("<p></p>", {
        html: ele + " {<br><span>width: " + OriginalResult + "%;" + " /* " + ActualTarget + " (originally " + target + ") / " + context + " */ " + "<br>border: " + border + "px; " + "<br>margin: " + MarginResult + "%; " + "<br>padding: " + PaddingResult+ "%;" + "<br> </span>}"
    }).hide().appendTo("#code-results").fadeIn();
   });

}); 

});
```

But when someone doesn't enter a number at all I get NaN in the results? How do I get rid of that with this code? Also I want 0 to still be displayed as 0 is that possible with this?

edit: actually I'd love for when someone doesn't enter a number rather than NaN I get 0 as the result, is that possible?

Comment: If you always want results, you can also prefix your number variables with `>>> 0`, which turns invalid numbers in 0. Side effect: The range of the number will be `[0, 4294967295]`.

Answer (score 4):

u can make a test by using this function isNaN()

```
var myNumber = 'hello';
if (isNaN(myNumber)) 
    myNumber = 0;

console.log(myNumber); // return 0
```

---

EDIT: An implementation to test multiple values:

```
(function(global, $) {
    function isNan(valuesOrg) {
        values = $.isArray(valuesOrg) ? valuesOrg : [valuesOrg];
        results = values.map(function(value) {
            return isNaN(value);
        });

        if (!$.isArray(valuesOrg)) {
            return results[0];
        }

        return results;
    }

    global.myIsNane = isNan;
})(window, jQuery);

console.info(myIsNane('gh'));
console.info(myIsNane(90));
console.info(myIsNane(['oo', 00, 'bb', 84]));
```

Comment: I added - if (isNaN(target, context, broder, margin, padding)) 
    myNumber = 0;

console.log(myNumber); // return 0
    
}); to the bottom of my code and it doesn't work. I'm sure I've done something in error here :S

Comment: Sir Lhassan I have a question how can I use isNan in multiple values?

Comment: Hi Sama, Please see EDIT section in my answer.